# Как обратится через js к css

Tags: javascript, css

есть вот такой элемент #m151 в css как к нему обратится через js? и передать параметр none

```
:-webkit-full-screen #m151{

display:block;   
}
```

пытался так но не выходит

```
  document.getElementById("#m151").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementsByClassName('m151')[0].style.display = 'none';
```

```js
var cvs=document.getElementById("canvas"); // подлкючаем канвас

var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d"); 





var bolshoi = new Image();
var wrapperbolshoi = document.createElement('spanbolshoi');
wrapperbolshoi.appendChild(bolshoi);

wrapperbolshoi.id = 'm151';



bolshoi.src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/22/12/35/potatoes-3098865_960_720.png";

$(bolshoi).on("click", function() {
launchFullScreen(document.body); 


});
document.body.appendChild(wrapperbolshoi);





















launchFullScreen(document.body); 

    
    // функция при полном экране 
    function launchFullScreen(element) {
    if(element.requestFullScreen) {
        element.requestFullScreen();
    } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if(element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
}
```

```css
#m151{
 position:absolute;
   top:90%;
   left:90%;
    height: 20vh; 
  width: 10vw;  

display:block;
}


:-webkit-full-screen #m151{

 position:absolute;
   top:90%;
   left:90%;
    height: 5vh; 
  width: 5vw;  

display:block;  
}

:-moz-full-screen #m151{
 position:absolute;
   top:90%;
   left:90%;
    height: 5vh; 
  width: 5vw;  

display:block;          
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="675"></canvas> <!-- полотно где отображается код -->
```

Comment: так вы же спрашиваете для #m151 а в js отбираете #wind разумеется что работать не будет правило для #m151

Comment: да не будет,но тут даже если указать там m151 всё ровно не сработает так как двойной элемент :-webkit-full-screen #m151

Comment: исправили ответ ...не надо вводить в заблуждение , будет если ваш элемент действительно имеет id="m151" , но на всякий случай вызовите в console.log

Comment: это элемент в полном экране,а есть точно такой же элемент без полного экрана. #m151 это без полного экрана и к нему он обращается.:-webkit-full-screen #m151 этот же элемент в полном экране до него не смог достучатся

Comment: обращайтесь к полному экрану на js innerWidth innerHeight

Comment: а если ещё проще то elem.classList.toogle("new"); и в этом new в css напишите что он 100vw 100vh и всё весь головняк

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

в комменарии подсказали что лучше использовать :

> elem.addEventListener('click', function(){... });

```html
<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .view {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #cc0000;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="elem">elem</div>


  <script>
    var elem = document.getElementById("elem");

    elem.onclick = function() {
      this.classList.toggle("view");
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Если аффтар вопроса позже захочет добавить еще какой-нибудь клик к этому элементу и забудет, что здесь был онклик... то новый клик будет работать, а этот - перестанет. Поэтому обычно надежнее писать `elem.addEventListener('click', function(){... });` вместо onclick

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME  хрен с ним , скажи как устроена анимация этой лошади?https://zed.run/

Comment: это не совсем то ,как обратится через js к вот этому элементу и сделать параметр none?:-moz-full-screen #m151

Comment: @MaximLensky https://i.gyazo.com/7f1ae8459a9cf6a748bc481942ebfe4e.png (скрин её кода) - а это хитрое SVG... http://www.clker.com/inc/svgedit/svg-editor.html - есть такой редактор, чтобы её нарисовать и получить координаты... а дальше долго и нудно настраивать SVG анимацию...

Comment: @Ivan912 , если в CSS на id тыкают через # клетку, то в JS его можно достать или через `document.querySelector('#m151');` или `document.getElementById('m151');` /в случае id второе предпочтительнее/

Comment: всё понял спасибо

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME нарисовать то я нарисую в svg интересует про Долго И Нудно